# Black Screen - Unsupported Resolution

Tags: nvidia, login, display, monitor, display-resolution

I have an ultra wide screen monitor from LG (29UC97C-B) which seems to be not supported by Ubuntu.

Shortly, before the Login screen should be visible, the monitore becomes black and prints something like "Outside Specification". The same happens if I start Ubunutu from the Install-Disc.

When I connect another monitor everything works fine and after connecting back to the LG monitor I also get an image with the resolution of the other monitor. But as soon as I restart or just logout, the screen becomes black again.

**Is there a way to set fixed resolutions like Full HD for Ubuntu, so that I could at least work with the monitor even if the ultra wide is not supported?**

At the moment I refreshed my system and I can not do anything because of this problem. I tested Ubuntu 14.03 and 15.04.

The graphics card is an `NVidia GTX 570` and the monitor is connected with the DVI graphics card output to the HDMI in of the monitor (Adapter is used). By the way, everything works fine on Windows 7, so it is not a damaged monitor or cable or adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just copy-paste one of my previous answers here:

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

The easiest thing to do is add that resolution using `xrandr` - [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) is a good guide. You would then need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
  xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**OR** you can go the easy way and use a program that does the above for you -  [ResolutionX.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx)